# Getting a 'forbidden' error on POST routes when switching SailsJs app to production on appfog

Tags: node.js, sails.js, appfog

Usually I can count on someone on Stack Overflow already asking a questions.  However, I can't seem to track one down so ... my first post!

I have recently pushed a SailsJs application for deployment on AppFog.  When running the app in both development or production mode on my local machine it runs perfectly.  When I run it on AppFog as development it runs fine as well.  However, as soon as I change the global variable in AppFog to set it to production mode I begin to get 'forbidden' errors when I try to POST to a 'create' route.  My gut tells me that there is something going on with the CSRF, but I don't know what.  If it is a CSRF issue wouldn't it also be occurring in development mode as well?

Thanks in advance.  I'm stuck here and I can find little Sails documentation and what's happening when it switches to production aside from minifing CSS and JS.

Comment: Hmm is there anything in the log?  If so, would you mind posting the error message? Also, would you mind posting your Sails version?

Comment: I'm using 0.9.8.  I was using 0.9.7, but upgraded to see if that would fix it.  I tried deploying to Heroku and it worked perfectly.  Something is happening in the minification process I believe.  As a test I pulled out all the socket javascript files from sails.  This let it run in production mode, but I don't think it was because socket was remove.  I think it was because that cause the 'production.js' file to error.  I know AppFog doesn't support sockets, but I didn't think it would cause problems because it would just pick a fall back.